# Disable invite banner

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

When I invite a player to a turn based match in iOS Game-Center a Game Center banner is shown on top of the screen in the receiving side (at least most of the times, the functionality seems to be shaky).

I don't want a banner, but I want to handle that invite programmatically instead. Is that possible? The problem is that I can't control the banner. In some views I just want to ignore it.